# Parsing julian date to month and day of month

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
   County Year  JD  Tot_P  Min_P
0  Ady     2000   1    127   10.03
1  Ady     2000   2    127   10.03
2  Ady     2000   3    127   10.03
3  Ady     2000   4    127   10.03
4  Ady     2000   5    127   10.03
```

Here JD is the julian day (1...365 for each day in the year; 1 - 366 for leap year). I want to add 2 more columns, 1 for month and 1 for day of month. Here is what I am doing right now:

```
from datetime import date
    df['MONTH'] = df[['Year','JD']].apply(lambda s: date.fromordinal(date(df.Year, 1, 1).toordinal() + df.JD - 1).month)
    df['DAY']   = df[['Year','JD']].apply(lambda s: date.fromordinal(date(df.Year, 1, 1).toordinal() + df.JD - 1).day)
```

However, I get the error:

```
TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to <type 'int'>", u'occurred at index Year')
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vectorized method and should be quite performant.

Read in the data

```
In [14]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='\s+')

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
  County  Year  JD  Tot_P  Min_P
0    Ady  2000   1    127  10.03
1    Ady  2000   2    127  10.03
2    Ady  2000   3    127  10.03
3    Ady  2000   4    127  10.03
4    Ady  2000   5    127  10.03
```

Create a datetime column directly; julian date is simply the number of days added to the starting date (and you subtract 1 because you are starting from day 1).

```
In [21]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'],format='%Y') + pd.to_timedelta(df['JD'],unit='D') - Timedelta('1D')

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
  County  Year  JD  Tot_P  Min_P       date
0    Ady  2000   1    127  10.03 2000-01-01
1    Ady  2000   2    127  10.03 2000-01-02
2    Ady  2000   3    127  10.03 2000-01-03
3    Ady  2000   4    127  10.03 2000-01-04
4    Ady  2000   5    127  10.03 2000-01-05
```

Their are lots of things you can do with the `.dt` accessor, see the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components)

```
In [23]: df.date.dt.day
Out[23]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64

In [24]: df.date.dt.month
Out[24]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
dtype: int64

In [25]: df.date.dt.year 
Out[25]: 
0    2000
1    2000
2    2000
3    2000
4    2000
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a few more steps, with some helper columns, but it seems to work:

```
df['y_ord'] = df.Year.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.toordinal(pd.to_datetime(x.astype(int), format="%Y")))
df['d_ord'] = df['y_ord'].astype(int) + df.JD.astype(int) - 1
df['DAY'] = df.d_ord.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromordinal(x).day)
df['MONTH'] = df.d_ord.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromordinal(x).month)
```